# Uploading node_modules to Nexus hosted NPM repository

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

We are building our project in offline build server. Thus we have to store and maintain all our project dependencies in local network Nexus.

I have created hosted NPM registry in Nexus following [this](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages) guide. I skipped the proxy and group part. Now I want to upload (and maintain) all the project NPM packages (node_modules) from my local workstation to this repository. I don't see upload button in the Nexus repository settings. How to properly upload and maintain NPM packages in Nexus NPM registry? Can this be done by the Nexus GUI, or do I have to use command line? Note the nexus is disconnected from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The UI does not handle transitive dependencies.

You can also use the rest API to manage components directly, and upload all your `.tgz` packages.

```
POST ​/v1​/components
```

For instance, to upload the package `my-npm-package-0.0.0.tgz` to the repository `npm-private` use the following:

```
curl -u user:password -X POST "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-private" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "npm.asset=@my-npm-package-0.0.0.tgz;type=application/x-compressed"
```

The complete live API specs can be found at endpoint `/#admin/system/api`

The official nexus documentation can be found at https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api

Comment: This helped me a lot when I tried just to publish a tgz to a Nexus repository - thank you

Answer (score 1):

UI upload for npm packages was added in version 3.7.0.

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Uploading+Components

Comment: How the UI upload handles transitive dependencies? The project has about 500 dependencies so uploading them one by one is out of question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to upload the `node_modules`.

You need to create a proxy and a group repository.

Then you can **delete** the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in your project and run `npm install`.

Because your hosted don't have those packages,it will **download** them from proxy.

Then you can see those packages in the group.

When you run `npm install` again,it will download form **Nexus** ,not **NPM**.

The download speed will be **very fast**.

Comment: I think the key here is **offline build server**, you seem to assume the offline server has access to the internet.